# Remove negative values from variables and keeping only values greater than equal to 0 in new variable

Tags: r

Newbie to R.

I have a Patient Data of 1 year. The original dataset includes patient's data which has more than 50 Variables such as Pat_id, age, race, lab test, HbA1c dates, values, HbA1c_baseline_date, Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_1, Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_2,... so on until Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_15.

The sample dataset includes Pat_ID, HbA1c_baseline_date, Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_1, Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_2, Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_3, Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_4, Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_5.

"PAt_id" - is unique patient id.

"HbA1c_baseline_date" - is the baseline HbA1c Date

"Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_" = is the difference between the HbA1c_Baseline dates and the respective follow up dates.

```
sampledata <- data.frame(
  Pat_ID = c(1123, 1134, 1138, 1139),
  HbA1c_Baseline_Date = c("10/2/2019", "8/28/2019", "10/16/2019", "9/30/2019"),
  Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_1 = c(-421, -261, 0, 0),
  Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_2 = c(-329, -168, NA, 95),
  Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_3 = c(-196, -142, NA, 245),
  Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_4 = c(-105, -141, NA, NA),
  Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_5 = c(0, 0, NA, NA),
  Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_6 = c(97, 89, NA, NA),
)
```

I want R to create a new variables such as "baseline", "followup_1" "followup_2", "followup_3", "followup_4", "followup_5", and so on until "followup_12" in the original dataset.

I want to R to scan through all the "Hb_m_days_HbA1c_date_"s column and remove negative values and find out "0" and keep that in the "baseline" column and any number after that should be in the next respective column "followup_1", "followup_2", and so on.

I tried to use library(tidyverse) but it did not help much.
The output of str(dataraw) :

```
data.frame':    852 obs. of  167 variables:
 $ Pat_id                      : int  10004 10010 10012 10013 10014 10015 10019 10021 10025 10030 ...
 $ practice_id                    : int  11 11 13 11 12 14 8 8 14 12 ...
 $ rph_id                         : int  7 7 1 7 10 1 2 2 1 10 ...
 $ index_date                     : chr  "2019-10-02" "2019-08-28" "2019-07-19" "2019-07-10" ...
 $ study_group                    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ age                            : int  67 56 39 34 31 72 48 57 59 46 ...
 $ gender                         : int  1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ race                           : int  3 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ medicare                       : int  1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ commercial                     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ hypertension                   : int  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ diabetes                       : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ cc_total                       : int  1 1 3 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ num_meds                       : int  11 16 8 4 7 5 8 14 8 16 ...
 $ sbp_baseline_value             : int  144 120 114 125 137 138 140 126 144 151 ...
 $ dbp_baseline_value             : int  60 76 72 84 78 82 98 84 70 96 ...
 $ hba1c_baseline_value           : num  9.2 11.2 11.1 10.4 11.3 10.3 12.8 10 13.1 9.6 ...
 $ awv_inclusion                  : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ diabetes_inclusion_9           : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ diabetes_inclusion_7           : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ bp_inclusion                   : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ dm_match_7                     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ dm_match_9                     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ awv_2019                       : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ dsm_dc_2019                    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ dsm_htn_2019                   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ diabetes_subset7               : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ diabetes_subset9               : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ WHITE                          : int  0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ BLACK                          : int  0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 ...
 $ OTHER                          : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DIABETES_SUPER7                : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ DIABETES_SUPER9                : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ hba1c_date                     : chr  "2019-10-02" "2019-08-28" "2019-10-16" "2019-09-30" ...
 $ hba1c_final_2019_date          : chr  "2019-10-02" "2019-08-28" "2019-10-16" "2019-09-30" ...
 $ Max..hba1c_relative_index_date.: int  0 0 89 82 149 -13 -15 -22 206 224 ...
 $ hba1c_endyear_value            : num  9.2 11.2 9.2 10.7 6.7 10.3 12.8 10 6.4 6.3 ...
 $ a1c_control_7_2019             : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ a1c_control_8_2019             : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ a1c_control_9_2019             : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ HbA1c.Poor.Control_2019        : int  1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ bp_date                        : chr  "2019-10-02" "2019-11-06" "2019-12-27" "2019-09-30" ...
 $ bp_final_2019_date             : chr  "2019-10-02" "2019-11-06" "2019-12-27" "2019-09-30" ...
 $ Max..bp_relative_index_date.   : int  0 70 161 82 261 -18 -15 0 310 223 ...
 $ bp_relative_index_date         : int  0 70 161 82 261 -18 -15 0 310 223 ...
 $ sbp_endyear_value              : int  144 133 128 139 135 138 140 126 127 148 ...
 $ dbp_endyear_value              : int  60 86 88 71 89 82 98 84 68 87 ...
 $ sbp_control_2019               : int  0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ dbp_control_2019               : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ bp_control_2019                : int  0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ acr_baseline_date              : chr  "2019-03-21" "2019-08-29" "2019-07-20" "2019-06-28" ...
 $ acr                            : num  39.5 6.5 6.9 3.8 NA 9.5 6.9 NA 17.7 6.9 ...
 $ eGFR_baseline_date             : chr  "2019-10-03" "2019-08-29" "2019-07-23" "2019-06-28" ...
 $ eGFR                           : int  92 98 40 124 60 86 52 79 86 65 ...
 $ HDL_baseline_date              : chr  "2019-03-21" "2019-08-29" "2019-02-28" "2019-06-28" ...
 $ HDL                            : int  41 37 44 55 36 54 42 NA 42 23 ...
 $ LDL_baseline_date              : chr  "2019-03-21" "2019-08-29" "2019-02-28" "2019-06-28" ...
 $ LDL                            : num  81 70 90 56 93 59 64 NA 91 NA ...
 $ TG_baseline_date               : chr  "2019-03-21" "2019-08-29" "2019-02-28" "2019-06-28" ...
 $ TG                             : int  215 115 205 86 180 88 70 NA 172 589 ...
 $ TC_baseline_date               : chr  "2019-03-21" "2019-08-29" "2019-02-28" "2019-06-28" ...
 $ TC                             : int  165 130 175 128 165 131 120 NA 167 147 ...
 $ Non.HDL                        : int  124 93 131 73 129 77 78 NA 125 124 ...
 $ VLDL_baseline_date             : chr  "2019-03-21" "2019-08-29" "2019-02-28" "2019-06-28" ...
 $ VLDL                           : num  43 23 41 17 36 18 14 NA 34 NA ...
 $ height_in_baseline             : num  62 64.5 62 NA 72 NA NA 60 68 72 ...
 $ weight_lbs_baseline            : num  280 192 237 NA NA ...
 $ index_date_month               : int  10 8 7 7 4 10 12 10 2 5 ...
 $ index_date_quarter             : int  4 3 3 3 2 4 4 4 1 2 ...
 $ smoking_status                 : int  2 3 2 3 2 3 3 2 2 1 ...
 $ elix_obesity                   : int  1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ elix_depression                : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ icd_10_chart                   : int  10 4 12 1 4 1 1 3 5 8 ...
 $ X_PS_                          : num  0.3575 0.3941 0.0882 0.2653 0.2291 ...
 $ X_Lps_2                        : num  -0.586 -0.43 -2.336 -1.019 -1.213 ...
 $ X_MATCHWGT_                    : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ X_MatchID_2                    : int  189 217 1 105 61 16 227 158 248 255 ...
 $ days_1                         : int  -421 0 -261 -13 -14 -467 -431 -380 -146 0 ...
 $ HbA1c_Date_1                   : chr  "2018-08-07" "2019-08-28" "2018-10-31" "2019-06-27" ...
 $ HbA1c_1                        : num  7.9 11.2 7 10.4 11.3 8.8 6.4 8 8.2 9.6 ...
 $ days_2                         : int  -329 NA -168 82 149 -13 -257 -22 -1 93 ...
 $ HbA1c_Date_2                   : chr  "2018-11-07" NA "2019-02-01" "2019-09-30" ...
 $ HbA1c_2                        : num  8.8 NA 7.7 10.7 6.7 10.3 6.8 10 13.1 5.9 ...
 $ days_3                         : int  -196 NA -142 232 NA NA -96 169 92 94 ...
 $ HbA1c_Date_3                   : chr  "2019-03-20" NA "2019-02-27" "2020-02-27" ...
 $ HbA1c_3                        : num  9.1 NA 8.1 11 NA NA 7.1 8.1 7.6 6 ...
 $ days_4                         : int  -105 NA -141 NA NA NA -15 NA 206 224 ...
 $ HbA1c_Date_4                   : chr  "2019-06-19" NA "2019-02-28" NA ...
 $ HbA1c_4                        : num  9.1 NA 8.2 NA NA NA 12.8 NA 6.4 6.3 ...
 $ days_5                         : int  0 NA 0 NA NA NA 190 NA NA NA ...
 $ HbA1c_Date_5                   : chr  "2019-10-02" NA "2019-07-19" NA ...
 $ HbA1c_5                        : num  9.2 NA 11.1 NA NA NA 9 NA NA NA ...
 $ days_6                         : int  97 NA 89 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ HbA1c_Date_6                   : chr  "2020-01-07" NA "2019-10-16" NA ...
 $ HbA1c_6                        : num  9.1 NA 9.2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ days_7                         : int  NA NA 168 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ HbA1c_Date_7                   : chr  NA NA "2020-01-03" NA ...
 $ HbA1c_7                        : num  NA NA 10.1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ days_8                         : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ... The list output is truncated.
```

The output dataset should look like this-

| Pat_id | baseline | followup_1 | Followup_2 | followup_3 | Followup_4 | Followup_5 | Followup_6 | Followup_7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1123 | 0 | 97 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1134 | 0 | 89 | 168 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1138 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1139 | 0 | 95 | 245 |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential option using tidyverse functions:

```r
library(tidyverse)

sampledata <- data.frame(
  Pat_ID = c(1123, 1134, 1138, 1139),
  HbA1c_Baseline_Date = c("10/2/2019", "8/28/2019", "10/16/2019", "9/30/2019"),
  Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_1 = c(-421, -261, 0, 0),
  Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_2 = c(-329, -168, NA, 95),
  Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_3 = c(-196, -142, NA, 245),
  Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_4 = c(-105, -141, NA, NA),
  Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_5 = c(0, 0, NA, NA),
  Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_6 = c(97, 89, NA, NA)
)

df1 <- sampledata %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("days")) %>% # pivot the dataset to long format
  group_by(Pat_ID) %>%                              # group results by patient ID
  mutate(followup = case_when(value < 0 ~ NA,            # if the value is < 0 make it NA
                              value == 0 ~ "baseline",       # if the value == 0, make it baseline
                              value > 0 ~ paste("followup",      # if the value is > 0
                                                cumsum(value > 0),     # count each occurrence
                                                sep = "_"))) %>%        # and create followup_1, followup_2 etc
  na.omit() %>%                                     # then delete lines that contain an NA (don't need them)
  pivot_wider(names_from = followup,                # and pivot the data back to wide format
              values_from = value,
              id_cols = Pat_ID) %>%
  ungroup()                                         # and ungroup the dataframe

df1
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   Pat_ID baseline followup_1 followup_2
#>    <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1   1123        0         97         NA
#> 2   1134        0         89         NA
#> 3   1138        0         NA         NA
#> 4   1139        0         95        245

# To add the new columns to your original dataframe
df2 <- sampledata %>%
  left_join(df1)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(Pat_ID)`

df2
#>   Pat_ID HbA1c_Baseline_Date Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_1 Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_2
#> 1   1123           10/2/2019                   -421                   -329
#> 2   1134           8/28/2019                   -261                   -168
#> 3   1138          10/16/2019                      0                     NA
#> 4   1139           9/30/2019                      0                     95
#>   Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_3 Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_4 Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_5
#> 1                   -196                   -105                      0
#> 2                   -142                   -141                      0
#> 3                     NA                     NA                     NA
#> 4                    245                     NA                     NA
#>   Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_6 baseline followup_1 followup_2
#> 1                     97        0         97         NA
#> 2                     89        0         89         NA
#> 3                     NA        0         NA         NA
#> 4                     NA        0         95        245
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for replying. The code did work! It worked perfect on the sample dataset I provided but I got an error while doing the same on the original dataset. As mentioned earlier my original dataset has more than 50 variables and these variables "Hb_m_days_HbA1c_Date_" are at the end of the dataset. Is there any way I can continue making new variables such as "baseline", "followup_"s in the same original dataset?

Comment: It would be of great help if you also let me know how to use the same code in the original dataset and get the same output. Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: I've edited my answer - does that work with your actual data?

Comment: It did not work on my original dataset. So what I did was in the code you provided I substituted "sampledata" with my original dataset named "dataraw" and run the code. When I view(df1) it has no data available in table and I did  not get any error too. As it had no data in df1 the leftjoin function did not work. Please correct me if I am making any error here.

Comment: Are you able to share your data? I.e. edit your post to include the output of `str(dataraw)`?

Comment: Yes! I have edited my post. Do you want me to add the output of ls(dataraw) as well?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use `starts_with("days")`? I.e. see my edited answer

Comment: Hey!! It did work!! Thank You so much for your help. I am grateful to you.